# Talend ETL - Is it possible to forcefully include components into subjob?

Tags: talend

Please see the attached image. [image]

I want the subjob (4) to execute only when subjob (1) including (2) and (3) is completed successfully. Hence, I want to forcefully include component (2) and (3) into subjob (1). I am trying to drag (2) and (3) into (1) but this doesn't seem to work. Is this possible in Talend ETL?

Currently, I have subjob (4) execute when subjob (1) completes excluding (2) and (3) as is seen in image. Please help clear my understanding.

Comment: I don't understand your question; what do you mean by drag 2 and 3 into 1 ? As it is now, subjob 4 will execute only when 1, 2 and 3 complete successfully, which seems to be what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Currently (1), (2) and (3) is each a separate subjob (denoted by sky blue rectangles). I want to have only (1) as a subjob. The (2) and (3) should also reside into subjob (1) and not as separate subjobs themselves.

Comment: Why would you want them to reside in subjob 1 ? Since subjob 4 will execute after the other subjobs have finished successfuly.
At any rate, tJava components are not flow components, and will have a subjob of their own, you can't force them to be a part of another subjob.

Comment: Then it is visually deceptive. I was assuming that (2), (3) and (4) will start executing simultaneously after the subjob (1) completes.

Comment: Yep. Here's an interesting article on the subject: https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/What-is-the-difference-between-OnSubjobOK-and-OnComponentOK/ta-p/21696

Comment: @iMezouar - if you can put it as an answer with the URL reference, I will mark it as accepted. Thanks for your help on this.